# Constraint on parameters in lmfit

Tags: python, lmfit

I am trying to fit 3 peaks using [lmfit](https://lmfit.github.io/lmfit-py/) with a skewed-Voigt profile (this is not that important for my question). I want to set a constraint on the peaks centers of the form:

```
peak1 = SkewedVoigtModel(prefix='sv1_')
pars.update(peak1.make_params())
pars['sv1_center'].set(x)

peak2 = SkewedVoigtModel(prefix='sv2_')
pars.update(peak2.make_params())
pars['sv2_center'].set(1000+x)

peak3 = SkewedVoigtModel(prefix='sv3_')
pars.update(peak3.make_params())
pars['sv3_center'].set(2000+x)
```

Basically I want them to be 1000 apart from each other, but I need to fit for the actual shift, x. I know that I can force some parameters to be equal using `pars['sv2_center'].set(expr='sv1_center')`, but what I would need is `pars['sv2_center'].set(expr='sv1_center'+1000)` (which doesn't work just like that). How can I achieve what I need? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Just do:

```
pars['sv2_center'].set(expr='sv1_center+1000') 
pars['sv3_center'].set(expr='sv1_center+2000')
```

The constraint expression is a Python expression that will be evaluated every time the constrained parameter needs to get its value.